# Jqgrid how to add "delete button"

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I want to incorporate delete button in the actions column. It can come beside can cel button. This is how it looks as of now- 
[image: Check here]
This is my code:

```
    <script>
    var task_link = "http://localhost/cssdeck/dashboard/dashboar.php?Emp_ID=";
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#emp_grid").jqGrid({
    url: "getGridData.php?q=3",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ["Emp Id", "Emp Name", "Emp Start Date", "Emp End Date" ,       "Percent", "Status","ACTIONS"],
    colModel: [
    { name: "emp_id",index:"emp_id",editable:true,formatter: formatEmpID},
    { name: "emp_name",index:"emp_name",align:"center",editable:true},
    { name:    "emp_startDate",index:"emp_startDate",sorttype:'date',edittype:"text",formatter:   'date',formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y/m/d', newformat: 'm/d/Y'},editable:true,
                  editoptions: {
                            // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon    initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                            // use it to place a third party control to customize  the toolbar
                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                                    //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                    maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                    showOn: 'focus'
                                });
                            }
                        },

      searchoptions: {
    dataInit: function(elem) {
        $(elem).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
        showOn: 'focus'
        });
    }
}

},
       { name:   "emp_endDate",index:"emp_endDate",sorttype:'date',edittype:"text",formatter:  'date',formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y/m/d', newformat: 'm/d/Y'},editable:true,
                   editoptions: {
                             // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon  initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                             // use it to place a third party control to  customize the toolbar
                             dataInit: function (element) {
                                 $(element).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                                    //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                    maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                    showOn: 'focus'
                                });
                            }
                        },
      searchoptions: {
       dataInit: function(elem) {
           $(elem).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
           //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
           maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
           showOn: 'focus'
           });
       }
   }

   },

       { name: "percentComplete",index:"percentComplete",editable:true},
       { name:   "emp_status",index:"emp_status",editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:  {value:"Onboarding:Onboarding;Released:Released"}},
     {name:'act',index:'act', width:130,sortable:false}
     ],
     rowNum:10,
     rowList:[10,20,30],
     pager: '#pemp_grid',
     loadonce:true,
     ignoreCase: true,
     viewrecords: true,
     autowidth:true,
     cmTemplate: { title: false },
     height:'100%',
     gridComplete: function(){
        var ids = jQuery("#emp_grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            var cl = ids[i];
            be = "<input style='height:22px;width:40px;' type='button'   value='Edit' onclick=\"jQuery('#emp_grid').jqGrid('editRow','"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
            se = "<input style='height:22px;width:40px;' type='button'  value='Save' onclick=\"jQuery('#emp_grid').jqGrid('saveRow','"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
            ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button'  value='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#emp_grid').jqGrid('restoreRow','"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                jQuery("#emp_grid").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
                }   
    },
editurl: "update.php",
caption: "Employee Details"
}); 
$("#emp_grid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pemp_grid",{edit:false,del:false,refresh: false, search: false} );
$("#emp_grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
});
function formatEmpID(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            var link = task_link + cellvalue;
            return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
        }
    </script>
```

I have been trying to achieve this from past 2 days but all effort in vain. 
Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You can delete the row from the grid with the `delRowData` method. But you need to write your own function that makes the AJAX call to delete from the server.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to do that

Comment: You can just remove `gridComplete` and add `formatter: "actions"` in the column `act` (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) a demo which uses `formatter: "actions"` ). It's important that you write which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).